# Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: c, sockets, centos, ipv6

The following code is a socket programming sample for a TCP client.

But when I run this, connect() is returned as Address family not supported by protocol.

I have heard, this problem will happen if the platform does not support ipv6.

But AF_INET I wrote is ipv4.

Also my server, that is CentOS6.4, is configured within an inet6 addr .

Does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int
main(){
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int sock;
    char buf[32];
    int n;
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    perror("socket");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(12345);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&server,sizeof(server));
    connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server));
    perror("connect");
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
    n = read(sock,buf,sizeof(buf));
    perror("read");
    printf("%d,%s\n",n,buf);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code passes the wrong destination address and wrong number of arguments to `inet_pton()`. (For the latter the compiler should have warned you about, btw)

This line

```
 inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server, sizeof(server));
```

should be

```
 inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr);
```

Verbatim from [`man inet_pton`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html):

> **int inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst);**
>
> **AF_INET**
>
> [...] The address is converted to
>                 a struct in_addr and copied to dst, which must be sizeof(struct in_addr) (4) bytes (32 bits) long.

---

Not related to the problem, but also an issue, is that `read()` returns `ssize_t` not `int`.

The following lines shall be adjusted:

```
int n;
[...]
printf("%d, %s\n", n, buf);
```

to become:

```
ssize_t n;
[...]
printf("%zd, %s\n", n, buf);
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the server address like this;

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Comment: Situation’s changed to 'Connection refused'. Looks like step forward.

Comment: I'm sure the `Connection refused` means the server is not exist or the server down

Comment: "*Connection refused*" means the ip-address is reachable, but there is noone listening on the specified port, so the machine with the ip-address "*refuses*" to connect.

Comment: My server doesn’t work. I’ll ask at another thread so that this thread will be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I seen this error during [bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html). Cause was of using `localhost` instead of IP:

```
./myprogram localhost:7777
*** exception! `bind' failed for `localhost:7777' (97, Address family not supported by protocol)

./myprogram 127.0.0.1:7777
OK! Listening...
```

In addition: this error happens on one Linux host and does not appear on another. I check and compare network settings on this machines (`lo` device, /etc/hosts, /etc/host.conf, etc) and not found essential difference

Comment: very annoying, did you find a solution?

Comment: It happens too a lot of time ago… do not remember( But the simplest way from the answer is to use IP instead of hostname

Answer (score -1):

run this two lines in terminal

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```