# Socket C - Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: c, sockets, system-calls

So I am trying to create a packet sniffer in C. After following the [man7 page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) I inferred that the socket function should look like this

```
.....
int socketfd = socket(AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL));
if(socketfd < 0)
{
    perror("Socket Error");
    return 0;
}
.....
```

And the error is `Socket Error: Address family not supported by protocol` I looked it up but didn't find a solution to my problem. There is a question that [looks similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368832/address-family-not-supported-by-protocol) but it's not even with the socket syscall. I didn't really try anything else because I didn't find any alternative parameters to put in the function.

Comment: Which platform are you targetting? Not all platforms support `AF_PACKET`.  Is there a reason why you are writing a sniffer using a RAW socket and not an actual sniffing library, like libpcap?

Comment: What do you mean by "platform"

Comment: By platform, I mean OS.  Windows, Unix/Linux (which distro?), etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ubuntu to compile the program (GCC). It is a WSL if it matters . The OS is windows.

Comment: WSL stands for "Windows Subsystem for Linux", so you are trying to run a Linux app on Windows?  Per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/run-linux-natively-on-windows-10: "***WSL does not support AF_PACKET** for security restrictions. This means that you won't be able to put a Wi-Fi adapter in promiscuous mode (or monitor mode), and tools that require raw sockets to function properly won't work, such as Nmap.*"

Comment: If you google "WSL AF_PACKET" the only results you will see will state something like "WSL is not supporting AF_PACKET"